# Behavior of fputs() on MacOSX is not normal

Tags: c, macos

Assume that test.txt is like this:

> aaaaa
>   aaaaa
>   aaaaa

And test code is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *f = fopen("test.txt", "r+");
  char buf[100];

  fgets(buf, 100, f);
  fputs("bbb", f);

  fclose(f);

  return 0;
}
```

Of course, my intent is result file might be like this:

> aaaaa
>   bbbaa
>   aaaaa

But on MacOSX, it's like this:

> aaaaa
>   aaaaa
>   aaaaa
>   bbb

fputs() doesn't return any error, and when ftell() is put after fgets(), it points 6 exactly.
Is that a bug? On Linux, it is done well as I want.

Comment: @user3121023 it works but why?

Comment: Perhaps, the line-ending in your file isn't recognized and `fgets()` reads all 3 "lines" into buf? What gets printed if you put `puts(buf);` between your `fgets()` and `fputs()` ?

Comment: It seems that buffering causes `fgets` to read more than needed from the file handle, in this case, to the end of file.

Comment: @hamstergene No `fgets` does not read more than one line. Printing the `but` after the `fgets` just shows (as expected) `aaaa`

Comment: @user3121023 You should post your comment as an answer: as it works (testes on OS X)

Comment: @Matteo `fgets` *returns* no more than one line, but its implementation may easily read into the internal buffer of `FILE` more than that. This is why `ftell` returns 6 (which is correct), however, the actual file ends up positioned further than that.

Comment: @user3121023: _ALL_ platforms require a call to a positioning function when switching between in- and output operations on files _unless_ your last input operation encountered EOF. The standard is very clear about this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html :

> Note that ANSI C requires that a file positioning function
>   intervene between output and input, unless an input operation
>   encounters end-of-file.

If you don't do that, you're into the territory of "undefined behaviour" i.e. anything can happen. So, to continue quoting:

> Therefore it is good practice [...] to put an fseek(3) or
>   fgetpos(3) operation between write and read operations on
>   such a stream.

You're just seeing how Apple decided to do it, which is their right.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is invoking undefined behaviour according to the standard (7.19.5.3 The fopen function):

> 6. When a file is opened with update mode ('+' as the second or third character in the
>      above list of mode argument values), both input and output may be performed on the
>      associated stream. However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an
>      intervening call to the fflush function or to a file positioning function (fseek,
>      fsetpos, or rewind), and input shall not be directly followed by output without an
>      intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters endof-file.
>      Opening (or creating) a text file with update mode may instead open (or create) a
>      binary stream in some implementations.

It would appear that the implementation you're dealing with just sets the pointer to the end of the file if you don't add an `fseek` call in between the read and write. That may hold true for clang, but other systems might opt to handle that situation differently